# Is there a way to control timer ring volume in headset on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, headphones, sound-volume

When a timer runs out and I wear a headset, the ring volume in the headset is **very** loud. The phone ring volume is ok.

I wonder if there’s a way to control the timer ring volume so that it’s more moderate?

Comment: I can't test for this particular one, but many such controls can be adjusted *whilst that event type is happening* from the regular volume up/down buttons.

Comment: @Tetsujin Do you mean there are volume settings that can only be controlled that way (when they’re happening)? I thought that all these settings were also available somewhere in settings, but maybe I’m wrong?

Comment: It's like almost everything except the phone ringer [which you can only adjust when it's not ringing] Such as phone call voice volume, Music etc can be controlled whilst they're happening. Actually, I just tried it with Alarm over the speaker & all it does is cancel the ringer. I think it's covered under the main ringer volume.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the maximum wanted decibel level in Headphone Safety.

For this, go to *Settings > Sounds & Haptics > Headphone Safety*, enable **Reduce Loud Sounds** and move the slider to the maximum decibel level you want (85 decibels is fine for me).

[image: Screenshot taken on iPhone of the Reduce Loud Sounds parameter (and slider)]

For more information about this, check out the [Use headphone audio level features on iPhone](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/use-headphone-audio-level-features-iph64ac7296f/ios) article.